# Why does matplotlib magnitude_spectrum function seem to show wrong magnitudes?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

I created a 1 second long audio sample consiting of two sine waves and then used matplotlibs magnitude spectrum function to plot the spectrum and the results seem to be wrong. The two waves have the exact same amplitude throughout the one second audio sample, and yet the magnitudes are vastly different. This seemed weird to me, so I have also used numpys functions to plot the DFT and the magnitudes are the exact same, as I think they should be. The resulting plots are shown in the image below. Does anyone know, why that might be? Did I do anything wrong in my code? Any help will be much appriciated.

Minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sr = 20000
freq1 = 200
freq2 = 100
duration = 1

x = np.linspace(0, duration, sr * duration)
y = np.concatenate([0.5*np.sin(freq1 * 2 * np.pi * x[:10000]) + 0.5*np.sin(freq2 * 2 * np.pi * x[:10000]), np.sin(freq1 * 2 * np.pi * x[10000:15000]), np.sin(freq2 * 2 * np.pi * x[15000:20000])])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(12, 10))

ax[0].plot(x, y)
ax[0].axis(xmin=0, xmax=1)
ax[0].set_xlabel('Time [s]')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Amplitude [-]')

ax[1].magnitude_spectrum(y, Fs=sr, color='C1')
ax[1].axis(xmin=0, xmax=500)
ax[1].set_xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Magnitude [-]')

ax[2].plot(np.fft.rfftfreq(sr, d=1/sr), np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y, norm='ortho'))/100)
ax[2].axis(xmin=0, xmax=500)
ax[2].set_xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
ax[2].set_ylabel('Magnitude [-]')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Image showing the signal and the two magnitude spectra, orange one is from matplotlib and blue one from numpy.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is related to the window used in the matplotlib. By default, it uses Hanning window, so change to window type to window_none. Also the way the scaling is done is different in both cases. By doing following changes, you will see them both match.

```
from matplotlib import mlab
ax[1].magnitude_spectrum(y, Fs=sr, color='C1', window=mlab.window_none)

ax[2].plot(np.fft.rfftfreq(sr, d=1/sr), np.abs(np.fft.rfft(y))/sr)
```

results in [image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, you even explained the scaling which I did not understand, perfect. Thank you very much!